# Strange loading behavior on EF 6.1.1

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I made a simple example to examine EF lazy loading behavior and found out something very strange. My example as follow:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}

class Bar
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int FooID {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("FooID")]
    public virtual Foo Foo {get;set;}
}

class Context : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Foo> Foo {get;set;}
     public DbSet<Bar> Bar {get;set;}
}

class Demo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        var foos = ctx.Foo.ToList();
        var bars = ctx.Bar.ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's a one-to-many relationship between `Foo` and `Bar`. The expected behavior here is both `Foo` and `Bars` properties inside those classes will be lazy loaded. But here something unexpected happened.

If I run both line

```
var foos = ctx.Foo.ToList();
var bars = ctx.Bar.ToList();
```

Lazy loaded work perfectly.

But if I only run one of those line:

```
var foos = ctx.Foo.ToList();
//var bars = ctx.Bar.ToList();
```

Or

```
//var foos = ctx.Foo.ToList();
var bars = ctx.Bar.ToList();
```

In this case, lazy load does not work, I only got `null` in `Bars` or `Foo` property. Can someone explain me what is happening here?

**EDIT**

Clumsy me, turned out that this behavior happen because I didn't add `public` modifier to class definition of `Foo` and `Bar`

Comment: This is as it should be. "Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed." You need to explicitly access the property in order to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not idea of what lazy loading is.

Lazy loading happens when

- you load an entity from the DB (without including related entities)
- while you're stilll in the context you access one of its navigation properties. At this moment the context will query the DB to populate the navigation property

I.e. if you have an entity like this

```
public class Parent
{
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollecton<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

When you do this

```
var parent = myContext.Parents.First()
```

You get a parent, without its children from the DB. At this moment, provided the context has not been disposed, you can do this:

```
foreach(var child in parent.Children)
```

If this is the first time you access the `Children` property the context will query the DB and populate it. That's lazy loading. Any other thing it's not lazy loading.

Please, read this article to understand all the possible ways to load related entities (eager, explicit or lazy):

[Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)